# Disposing of an SQL dataset

Tags: c#, sql, .net, error-handling

I am getting a compiler warning when running my code analysis.  It is CA2202.  It is saying that I have not properly disposed my dataset through all exception paths.  Here is the code:

```
    private System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
    {
        DataSet dat_set = new DataSet(); 

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_string))
        {
            try
            {
                da_1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, conn);
                dat_set.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                da_1.Fill(dat_set, "Table_Data_1");
                MainForm.wasSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        return dat_set;
    }
```

Any thoughts on how to properly dispose this object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to dispose it. Otherwise your client code will be working off a disposed object and you'll be getting `ObjectDisposedException`'s left and right.

The question is, *does your client code **really** need a `DataSet`?* or does it simply need a *representation* of the data?

If it actually needs to be working off a `DataSet` object, you can ignore the warning, as long as your client code *is* properly disposing it when it's done working with it.

If all you need is a representation of the data, then the solution is to *not* return a `DataSet`, but some `IEnumerable<Foo>` or `IReadOnlyList<Foo>`, where `Foo` is a Plain Old CLR Object (POCO - a simple class exposing nothing more than property getters and setters).

Instead of using a `DataSet`, you could use a `SqlDataReader`, which you obtain by executing a `SqlCommand` - note that returning an `IEnumerable<T>` makes it possible to `yield return` your results:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetData(string connectionString, string sqlStatement)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
    using(var command = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection)) 
    {
       connection.open(); 
       using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
       { 
            while (reader.Read()) 
            { 
               yield return new Foo
                   {
                       Bar = (int)reader[0], // retrieve by field index, or..
                       Something = (string)reader["SomeField"] // retrieve by field name
                   };
            } 
       } 
    }
}
```

---

Couple of other points:

- Don't use underscores in identifiers. Use the more standard `camelCase` instead.
- Don't abbreviate or disemvowel identifiers. There's no reason to do this.
- Don't update the UI in a method whose responsibility is to retrieve data.
- If you don't know what to do with an exception, let it bubble up, the client code is more likely to know what to do (e.g. pop a messagebox, or show a meaningful error message in the UI).
- Use objects. The instruction `MainForm.wasSuccess = true;` looks very very much like you're accessing a `static` member, which is bad because `static` things belong to a *type*, as opposed to an *instance*.